# Grails 2.4.3 ERROR GrailsContextLoaderListener java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/security/Init

Tags: grails, spring-security, classnotfoundexception, saml-2.0, grails-plugin

I am getting following error when I execute grails run-app, I am trying to run my grails application locally but unable to do so

Following is the error from Stacktrace

### Stacktrace

```
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
2017-01-24T07:52:41.255+05:00 uptime="19368", level="ERROR", class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener", thread="localhost-startStop-1:", message="Error initializing the application: org/apache/xml/security/Init"
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/security/Init
    at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.initializeXMLSecurity(DefaultBootstrap.java:174)
    at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap(DefaultBootstrap.java:90)
    at org.opensaml.PaosBootstrap.bootstrap(PaosBootstrap.java:27)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xml.security.Init
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:175)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:147)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I can provide more details if you want, can anyone help why is this happening?

Comment: check if you have xmlsec lib

Comment: great thanks @SandeepPoonia I have added `compile 'org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:2.0.8'` in dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy file and it resolved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I was missing xmlsec lib, I solved this by adding

```
compile 'org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:2.0.8'
```

in dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy file and it resolved my problem :)